# How to add has_many through using the controller for specific cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the Students and Teachers table connected through a join table called Classes.
My goal is to add a teacher to a student profile by first checking if the teacher already exists and if not then make a new teacher profile. The classes are not important for the moment. Can somebody push me in the right direction because I'm merely a beginner and I could not find a solution in the guides.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classes
  has_many :teachers, through: :classes
end

class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :teacher
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :classes
  has_many :students, through: :classes
end
```

Thanks for helping a rookie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said 'Classes not important at the moment' but you can't connect Student & Teacher without a Class.

If you would have direct relation with Teacher, I would do;

1-

```
@student.teachers << @teacher unless @student.teachers.include?(@teacher)
```

2-

```
@student.teachers.find_or_create_by(params[:teacher])
```

3-

```
#Rails 3
@teacher = @student.teachers.find_or_initialize_by_id(params[:teacher_id])
@teacher.save
```

4-

```
student = @class.build_student
teacher = @class.build_teacher

student.teachers << teacher

student.save
teacher.save
```